# How to obtain some value on json

Tags: javascript, html

```
   var json = [
   {
      "bbox":[
         24.24112319946289,
         15.165281295776367,
         560.5425834655762,
         457.0700454711914
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.8514186143875122
   },
   {
      "bbox":[
         291.99377059936523,
         84.65291976928711,
         315.9793281555176,
         376.3008499145508
      ],
      "class":"tv",
      "score":0.8043261766433716
   },
   {
      "bbox":[
         296.79737091064453,
         353.7140464782715,
         252.2602081298828,
         114.29803848266602
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.5516218543052673
   }
]
```

Hi, I need help, I need to obtain data all 'class : person' from json above. How to do that?

Comment: thankyou for @kanishk Anand for helping editing my question :)

Comment: it'll be better if you can some more context to the question? Like the expected output, for the community to get better understanding of the question.

Comment: Yes. What do you mean 'obtain data'? What *exactly*? And where do you want it? And what have you tried??

Comment: okey thankyou again @kanishk anand, I guess I need the whole value from { , till } for class : person. sorry for nuub languange hehe

Comment: @wazz i need the value from beginning {, till } for all class : person. I already try to convert it to string and search for the word but I found that is wasting time and resource hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```js
const ids = ["person"];
const data = [
   {
      "bbox":[
         24.24112319946289,
         15.165281295776367,
         560.5425834655762,
         457.0700454711914
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.8514186143875122
   },
   {
      "bbox":[
         291.99377059936523,
         84.65291976928711,
         315.9793281555176,
         376.3008499145508
      ],
      "class":"tv",
      "score":0.8043261766433716
   },
   {
      "bbox":[
         296.79737091064453,
         353.7140464782715,
         252.2602081298828,
         114.29803848266602
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.5516218543052673
   }
];

const data2 = data.filter( i => ids.includes( i.class ) );

console.info( data2 );
```

Comment: thankyou @Kamran Khalid, I already try your code and it works :))

Comment: @ianzzz Please mark it done :)

Comment: I'm forget hehehe. thankyou again :)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]:

You can `filter` the array to get the desired object:

```
const person = json.filter((item) => item.class === 'person')
```

This will return the object having `class` key's value as `person`

```
[ 
   {
      "bbox":[
         24.24112319946289,
         15.165281295776367,
         560.5425834655762,
         457.0700454711914
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.8514186143875122
   },{
      "bbox":[
         296.79737091064453,
         353.7140464782715,
         252.2602081298828,
         114.29803848266602
      ],
      "class":"person",
      "score":0.5516218543052673
   }
]
```